# Is there a handy utility to quickly test POCOs for updating DB via EF without writing MVC code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

Just wondering whether there is a handy tool that takes a POCO and allows one to enter data into the DB via EF without having to write MVC code. Some EF designers have grids that attempt to do this, but some come unstuck when identity ID cols are involved.

Thanks.

Comment: EF has absolutely nothing to do with MVC.  MVC and EF are two different technologies and are unrelated.  They are simply often used together.  As such, no.. you don't need to write MVC code to use EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/).  In the more advanced usage, you can include namespaces from assemblies and use the POCO's defined in them.